# Form.ShowDialog(); trowing a System.OutPfMemoryException C#

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, showdialog

I'm developing a form to my college project to show a product but when I call that form with the `formName.ShowDialog()` the Visual Studio trows me a `OutOfMemoryException`. The weird part is that I have other forms that do the same thing with more steps and none of them throws that error. The code is bellow.

This is where I call the form.

```
private void dtgProduzir_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dtgProduzir.Rows[dtgProduzir.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["clIdProducao"].Value);
    ExibicaoProducao fepc = new ExibicaoProducao();
    fepc.IdProducao = id;
    fepc.ShowDialog();
    CarregarGrids();
}
```

This is the form class:

```
using ERP_Serralheria.Dal;
using ERP_Serralheria.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ERP_Serralheria.Desktop_Chapa
{
    public partial class ExibicaoProducao : Form
    {
        public ExibicaoProducao()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int IdProducao = 0;
        private void ExibicaoProducao_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (IdProducao == 0)
                {
                    //Cadastro de produção

                }
                else
                {
                    //Vizualização de uma produção
                    ProducaoChapa pc = new ProducaoChapa();
                    ProducaoChapaDal pcdal = new ProducaoChapaDal();
                    pc = pcdal.RetornaProducaoChapa(IdProducao);

                    lblIdProducao.Text = pc.Id.ToString();
                    lblIdVenda.Text = pc.Venda.Id.ToString();
                    cmbPatio.SelectedValue = pc.Patio.Id;
                    txtProdutor.Text = pc.Produtor.Nome;
                    txtVendedor.Text = pc.Venda.Usuario.Nome;
                    txtValor.Text = pc.ValorVenda.ToString();
                    txtPeso.Text = pc.Peso.ToString();
                    txtQuantidade.Text = pc.Quantidade.ToString();
                    txtLargura.Text = pc.Largura.ToString();
                    txtAltura.Text = pc.Altura.ToString();
                    txtObservacao.Text = pc.Observacao;
                    dtEntrega.Value = pc.Venda.DataEntrega;
                    if (pc.DataProducao.Year > 2019)
                        dtProducao.Value = pc.DataProducao;
                    cmbUrgencia.SelectedIndex = pc.Urgencia - 1;

                    //Carregar a imagem
                    txtIdChapa.Text = pc.Chapa.Id.ToString();
                    txtNomeCHapa.Text = pc.Chapa.Descricao;
                    pctImagem.BackgroundImage = pc.Chapa.Imagem;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fepc.ShowDialog()` does this line throws exception?

Comment: Just found out the issue is caused by the picturebox. I removed the picturebox and it worked.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, that line throw the exception.

Comment: You are probably recursively calling the same code in an endless loop.